# Has a goalkeeper ever scored in field hockey?

Tags: trivia, goalkeeper, field-hockey

I know nowadays a goalkeeper can't go further than the 23 metre area and be involved in play. But they can take a penalty stroke. So, does anyone knows of a goal scored by a goalkeeper in either international or high level professional field hockey?

Comment: I've reduced the scope to something answerable. Gabriel, if you really not happy with the change you can revert it but it's then likely the question would be closed as "needs details or clarity".